# How to make an SDC File

Tags: digital-logic, pwm, sdc

Can anybody tell me how do you specify the values of an SDC file for a digital block design?

For example, I have built a PWM using counter and comparator and I need to determine the SDC values, timings, etc.

In general we want to have ideal values, but this doesn't make sense to reality.  How do we choose them?